# Can I use select statements when inserting into a table?

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `worklist`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `worklist` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ENTITY_TYPE_CODE` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `TYPE_CODE` bigint(20) NOT NUll,
  `NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=125 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;


Insert INTO code (DISPLAY, CODE_GROUP, CODE_KEY, ALIAS) VALUES ('Duplicate Claims Worklist', 'WORKLIST_TYPE', 'DUPLICATE_CLAIM_WORKLIST', 'Duplicate Claims Worklist');
INSERT INTO code (DISPLAY, CODE_GROUP, CODE_KEY, ALIAS) VALUES ('Claim', 'ENTITY', 'CLAIM', 'Claim');
INSERT INTO worklist (ENTITY_TYPE_CODE, TYPE_CODE) VALUES (SELECT ID FROM code WHERE CODE_GROUP = 'ENTITY' and CODE_KEY = 'CLAIM', SELECT ID from code where CODE_GROUP = 'WORKLIST_TYPE' and CODE_KEY = 'DUPLICATE_CLAIM_WORKLIST');
ALTER TABLE workitems ADD WORKITEMS_ID bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: Note: for some reason, StackOverFlow is giving me an error saying I cannot edit this post. Not sure why. I apologize.  See question below.

Comment: Here is the question: 
The last line of code is giving me errors, saying **"FlywaySqlScriptException: Error executing statement at line 20: INSERT INTO worklist (ENTITY_TYPE_CODE, TYPE_CODE) VALUES (SELECT ID FROM code WHERE CODE_GROUP = 'ENTITY' and CODE_KEY = 'CLAIM', SELECT ID from code where CODE_GROUP = 'WORKLIST_TYPE' and CODE_KEY = 'DUPLICATE_CLAIM_WORKLIST'): You have an error in your SQL syntax; ".**

  I am assuming it is because of the select statements. Can I not do this? What would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: You can use it like this: `insert into t1 (col1, col2) select colX, colY from t2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can you need to omit the Values keyword and do something like this

```
INSERT INTO code (DISPLAY, CODE_GROUP, CODE_KEY, ALIAS) 
  SELECT DISPLAY, CODE_GROUP, CODE_KEY, ALIAS 
  FROM SomeTable
```

Obviously you will need to include a where clause to control the select statement but that's basically it.

**EDIT:**

It would look something like this (code is untested and has been typed directly into the editor so may have some speeling mistooks.)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `worklist`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `worklist` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ENTITY_TYPE_CODE` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `TYPE_CODE` bigint(20) NOT NUll,
  `NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=125 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;


Insert INTO code (DISPLAY, CODE_GROUP, CODE_KEY, ALIAS) VALUES ('Duplicate Claims Worklist', 'WORKLIST_TYPE', 'DUPLICATE_CLAIM_WORKLIST', 'Duplicate Claims Worklist');
INSERT INTO code (DISPLAY, CODE_GROUP, CODE_KEY, ALIAS) VALUES ('Claim', 'ENTITY', 'CLAIM', 'Claim'); 
INSERT INTO worklist (ENTITY_TYPE_CODE, TYPE_CODE) SELECT A.ID, B.ID FROM (SELECT ID, 1 AS J FROM code WHERE CODE_GROUP = 'ENTITY' and CODE_KEY = 'CLAIM') A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ID, 1 AS J FROM code WHERE CODE_GROUP = 'WORKLIST_TYPE' and CODE_KEY = 'DUPLICATE_CLAIM_WORKLIST') B ON A.J = B.J;
ALTER TABLE workitems ADD WORKITEMS_ID bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL;
```